# Updating empty field with calculated data using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a current script that calculates how many wells are in each county.  Now, how do I update (fill in) the `COUNTIES` shapefile attribute fields of `'Well_Count'` and `'Density'`

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Data"

# For each county calculate the total numbers of wells that fall into that county, and update the county table with the total count.

wellsLayer = "C:\\Data\\Wells.shp"
countiesLayer = "C:\\Data\\COUNTIES.shp"

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(countiesLayer, wellsLayer, "CountyWellsJoin.shp")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("CountyWellsJoin.shp", ["COUNTY", "Join_Count"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        COUNTY = row[0]
        Join_Count = row[1]
        print "There are {0} wells in {1} County".format(Join_Count, COUNTY)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to move the join_count value back to the original shapefile, you would need to have some primary key field that you could use to identify the wells. If `COUNTY` field is unique, this would serve the purpose.

This could be done using a Python dictionary data structure.

`wells_per_county = {row[0]:row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("CountyWellsJoin.shp", ["COUNTY", "Join_Count"])}`

Now you could use `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("CountyWellsJoin.shp", ["COUNTY", "Well_Count"]) as upd_cur:
  for row in upd_cur:
    row[1] = wells_per_county[row[0]]
    upd_cur.updateRow(row)
```